# Keywords mapping error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

sysdtslog90 is a database table we use that logs SSIS information.  It has several column names that are also C# keywords: event and operator.

I used EF's Reverse Engineer Code First to create the Models and Mapping objects. The Model ends up with an @ in front of the name, and the Mapping does not. As a result, errors are thrown (pointing at the mapping file):

> ; expected
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 't' because it is not a delegate type

When I add the @ to the name in the mapping file then it will compile correctly. (In other words **t.@event** instead of **t.event**.)

*How can I change the Mapper so that it creates the same name as the model?*

**Mapping Snippet:** (without the @ )

```
public class sysdtslog90Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<sysdtslog90>
{
    public sysdtslog90Map()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.event)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
        
        this.Property(t => t.operator)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);
```

**Model snippet:**

```
public partial class sysdtslog90
{
...
  public string @event { get; set; }
...
  public string @operator { get; set; }
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.HasColumnName()` to map properties if your object's property and your table's column have different names:

```
this.Property(t => t.@event).HasColumnName("event");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "change the mapper." Do you mean is there some way to make the Reverse Engineer Code First tool place an `@` symbol in front of those properties when it generates the mapping code? I would say no, not unless you modify the source code of that tool.

But why not just tweak the mapping class yourself like you did to make it compile? If you change it so that it says `@event` and `@operator` inside those lambdas, those properties will still map to the `event` and `operator` columns in the database. The `@` prefix is just allowing you to use a C# keyword as an identifier, it isn't actually part of the identifier. Consequently, Entity Framework will not "see" the `@` symbol once the code is compiled, and therefore it will not attempt to use it in the column mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Year later I have the same. Here was my fix but unfortunately it does not work... fully.
Set your project to customize the T4 templates from the reverse engineer menus. Then open the Mapping.tt file. In there you will see how it is building the classes.

```
this.Property(t => t.<#= new string[] {"event", "operator"}.Contains(prop.Name.ToString())     ? "@@" + prop.Name.ToString() : prop.Name #>)
<#= string.Join("\r\n                ", configLines) #>;
```

This works fully for "operator" but for event it does this still:

```
this.Property(t => t.event)
```

"operator" looks good:

```
this.Property(t => t.@operator)
```

Hopefully if anyone reads this it might spur an answer. I am still working on it myself. Note, I also applied the same for the Table area of the class and while it is the exact code, the event does in fact get the @ symbol where it needs to be there. Very strange.

EDIT: So I simply did not save the .tt file. The above code works. I hope it helps someone. Be sure that after you edit the tt file you save it because the reverse engineer does not auto save those files.